# Bug in notification and displayed number of votes

Tags: bug, reputation, notifications

I have just a notification that a question has been up-voted with +1 notification, but when opened the question page found down vote -1 !

[see screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **not a bug**

The notification is telling you about the net reputation change, not the votes your question had.

When you received that notification, it was telling you of a net reputation change of +1 for that question, and it was then at net -1 score (1 upvote, 2 downvotes).

You had earned 5 rep for 1 upvote, and lost 4 rep for the 2 downvotes, totalling +1, exactly what the notification said.